# How to enable mod_security on Windows 2008 IIS

Tags: php, iis-7, mod-security, matomo

I am trying to install PIWIK (http://piwik.org) on Windows 2008 server and IIS 7.

PIWIK is using PHP and MySQL.

When I run the install process, I got the following error.
[image]

I don't know how can I enable mod_security and HTTP Authentication for Piwik.

At present, I am using Anonymous Authentication.

Please advice me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using Web Platform Installer to set it up?

http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/piwik.aspx

Comment: Finally, I found out that there is an Installer for Windows and it works as a charm.

Answer (score -1):

you need access to the apache conf i believe if i remember correctly.

Comment: Does it mean that I can't install PIWIK on IIS7?  Thanks.

Comment: do you have access to the apache & php conf's? if not the you might try contacting your web host, if you do lookin apache conf file for the mod

Comment: This doesn't address the question. Apache is not IIS.